# Сбой конфигурации nginx при использовании limit_req в location

Tags: nginx

Что происходит с конфигурацией Nginx при включении limit_req? Если эта строчка закомментирована, то сервер как положено выдает нужные файлы и все работает. Но стоит ее раскомментировать как начитает возвращаться ошибка 404 файл не найден. При этом это не срабатывание зоны - у нее другой код 503.
Во всех других Location при этом все работает по прежнему как надо.

```
location ^~ /mysql-admin/ {

    location /mysql-admin/themes/ {
        alias /home/username/www/myadmin/themes/;
    }

    location ~ ^/mysql-admin/(.+\.php)$ {
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-main.socket;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/username/www/myadmin/$1;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        #limit_req zone=pma_passwd burst=10 nodelay; <-- вот эта строчка
    }
}
```

Как просил один из отвечающих на вопрос. 
Вывод nginx -V:

nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie'

И еще переместил файлы phpMyadmin из /home/username/www/myadmin в /home/username/www/myadmin/mysql-admin и переписал конфиг следующим образом. После этого ограничение на число запросов срабатывает как нужно. Единственное при этом сервер выдает код ответа 404, а не 503

```
location ^~ /mysql-admin/ {

root /home/username/www/myadmin;    
access_log  off;
error_log  off;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-main.socket;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;

    limit_req zone=pma_passwd burst=7 nodelay;
    limit_req_status 503;
    limit_req_log_level error;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pma_passwd.log error;
}
```

}

Вопрос почему не работает первоначальный конфиг так и остается открытым. Там получается следующая ситуация - при включении зоны pma_passwd (она включается по условию $arg_pma_password в запросе) сервер всегда выдавал 404, при отсутствии все работало. Вот, кстати, как у меня идет создание самой зоны

```
map "$request_method:$arg_pma_password" $pma_passwd_input{
"~GET:.+" $binary_remote_addr;
default "";
}

limit_req_zone $pma_passwd_input zone=pma_passwd:10m  rate=1r/m;
```

Answer (score 1):

Модуль ngx_http_limit_req_module позволяет ограничить скорость обработки запросов по заданному ключу или, как частный случай, скорость обработки запросов, поступающих с одного IP-адреса. Ограничение обеспечивается с помощью метода “leaky bucket”.

Читаем маны тут - https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

дайте вывод

```
nginx -V
```

и что пишет в логах error

Comment: Дополнил вопрос и сделал то, что вы просили.